# Determine user location then redirect to different home page

Tags: jquery

I want to be able to change an image depending on the location the user has viewed the site from? Or alternatively navigate them to another page.

Ideally i would like to pick this up using jquery, however i'm not a 100% sure if this is effective.

For example, I would want to swap in a different image if the user was visiting the site from London. Can we be region specific?

Thanks
Gillian

---

Just got this to work with the help of beda0805

Here's the solution

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title>Location</title>
  <script type='text/javascript' src='//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js'></script>

  <script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
    $(window).load(function(){
    $.get("http://ipinfo.io", function (response) {
     if(response.region == 'London'){
       $("#address").append("<p>Your in London</p>");
     }
     if(response.region != 'London'){
       $("#address").append("<p>Your anywhere else</p>");
     }
    }, "jsonp"); 
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="address"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sure, there are ways to test the user's location. What have you tried?

Comment: Haven't tried anything yet, but have been googling for possible solutions and came across this http://jquery-plugins.net/jqIpLocation/jqIpLocation.html but wasnt sure whether IP was the right route to go.. if you have any google search recommendations they'd be most welcome :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a nice [tutorial](http://briancray.com/posts/find-web-visitors-location-javascript-google-api/).

You could use this to check if the user is from London:

```
google.loader.ClientLocation.address.city == 'London'
```

and use javascript to insert a picture into the div with id="yourinfo".

```
elem.src = 'images/london.jpg';
document.getElementById("yourinfo").appendChild("elem");
```

UPDATE:

Above API seems to be out of date. Working solution here: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zK5FN/2/) thanks to [Ben Dowling](https://stackoverflow.com/users/36191/ben-dowling)

Comment: Oh brilliant, thanks for that. Will give it a go. Never seen ClientLocation before... learn something new everyday. thanks again. will let you know how i get on

Comment: Thanks for the tutorial, just trying this now but keep getting the 'whoops' message. Any ideas? I've took a direct copy of the code from the tutorial. here's my page gillianbell.me.uk/location

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code used by the jqIpLocation plugin demo, which you were looking at. As you can see, it's pretty straight-forward.

```
$("#btnGetLocation").on("click", function () {

    if ($('#txtIP').val() != "") {
        $('#divIP').empty().append('<div style="padding:5px;"><img src="loader.gif" /></div>');

        $.jqIpLocation({
            ip: $('#txtIP').val(),
            locationType: 'city',
            success: function (location) {
                $('#divIP').empty();
                $('#divIP').append('<table class="table table-bordered table-striped">'
                + '<tr><td class="title">IP</td><td class="result">' + location.ipAddress + '</td></tr>'
                + '<tr><td class="title">Country</td><td class="result">' + location.countryName + '</td></tr>'
                + '<tr><td class="title">Country Code</td><td class="result">' + location.countryCode + '</td></tr>'
                + '<tr><td class="title">City</td><td class="result">' + location.cityName + '</td></tr>'
                + '<tr><td class="title">Region</td><td class="result">' + location.cityName + '</td></tr>'
                + '<tr><td class="title">Latitude</td><td class="result">' + location.latitude + '</td></tr>'
                + '<tr><td class="title">Longitude</td><td class="result">' + location.longitude + '</td></tr>'
                + '</table>');
            }
        });
    }

 })
```